# How to physically represent a parent-child relationship, with a favourite, enforcing constraints?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

I have a pair of logical entity relationships that must occur reasonably frequently.

Consider two entities `Parent` and `Child`. Unsuprisingly, each `Parent` has at least one or more `Children`.

Obvious so far.

Additionally, each `Parent` has exactly one **favourite** `Child`.

I have some limitations or requirements to inform the best solution,

- Both `Child` and `Parent` have a Primary Key which is an Indentity column.
- The solution must enforce integrity (as much as possible.) I want no way to have childless parents, parents without a favourite or orphaned children.
- I'd like simple and quick access to the favourite child of a parent.
- I'd like all children, including favourites to reside in the same table, so I can search across them without a union or join.
- I need to be able to insert data into the tables.

---

Here is where I am starting from, [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79b50)

```
CREATE TABLE [Parent]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [FavouriteChildId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Other] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [Child]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ParentId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Other] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Child] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Child_Parent]
        FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Parent]([Id])
);

ALTER TABLE [Parent]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Parent_FavouriteChild]
        FOREIGN KEY ([FavouriteChildId]) REFERENCES [Child]([Id]);
```

This satisfies all my requirments except that I cannot insert data.

Comment: You can't achieve your requirements since a single `INSERT` statement can only affect a single table and SQL Server doesn't support deferred constraints. Therefore you have a chicken-and-egg problem with "no orphans" and "no childless parents"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thats where I'm at, whats the best comprimise to work around it? I trying to think of the what other schema might offer a good solution, obviously, being able to insert is important.

Comment: I'd allow childless parents to exist. All of the rest is straightforward to achieve without that constraint.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is what I did last time this came up, I need help with my memory. Make it an answer if you feel like it.

Comment: Did you try the _OUTPUT_ clause to insert into two tables with one statement? Like _INSERT INTO Parent ... OUTPUT .. INTO Child ..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'd do. It's a slight relaxation on your constraints, but hopefully close enough:

```
CREATE TABLE [Parent]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Other] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [Child]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ParentId] INT NOT NULL,
    IsFavourite bit not null,
    FavouriteMarker as CASE WHEN IsFavourite = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -Id END persisted,
    FavouriteRef as CASE WHEN IsFavourite = 0 THEN 1 END persisted,
    [Other] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Child] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Child_Parent]
        FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Parent]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_Child_Favourite UNIQUE (ParentID,FavouriteMarker),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Child_FavouriteReference FOREIGN KEY (ParentID,FavouriteRef)
        references Child (ParentID,FavouriteMarker)
);
```

And some statements to exercise these tables:

```
insert into Parent (Other) values ('ABC'); --We'll assume this gets assigned ID 1

insert into Child (ParentId,IsFavourite,Other) values (1,0,'def') --Fails - no favourite child yet
insert into Child (ParentId,IsFavourite,Other) values (1,1,'ghi') --Succeeds
insert into Child (ParentId,IsFavourite,Other) values (1,1,'jkl') --Fails - no second favourite
insert into Child (ParentId,IsFavourite,Other) values (1,0,'mno') --Succeeds
insert into Child (ParentId,IsFavourite,Other) values (1,0,'pqr') --Succeeds
update Child set IsFavourite =
        CASE WHEN Other = 'mno' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
where Other in ('ghi','mno') --Succeeds, favourite changed
delete from Parent where Id = 1 --Fails - no orphans
```

So it does allow childless parents to exist, and the only parents without a favourite child are exactly those childless parents. The first `INSERT` that adds children for a particular parent may be a multi-row insert but has to include one (and exactly one) child marked as favourite. Thereafter, the favourite can be changed.

Comment: Constraints on computed columns, I like the idea, it makes inserts easier and enforces integrity.

Comment: @Jodrell - if you don't want the "no children unless at least one is a favourite" constraint enforced, then you don't need a computed column at all - you can just apply a [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx): `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Child_Favorites on Child (ParentID) WHERE IsFavourite = 1` and remove both computed columns. It was just a bit of happiness that it happened that the computed column could be used to achieve both the "one favourite" and "no children unless one is favourite" at the ssame time.